# MySQL usage by day

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like so

```
+----+----------+--------+
| ID |   Date   | Amount |
+----+----------+--------+
|  1 | 1/1/2020 |     40 |
|  1 | 1/2/2020 |     50 |
|  2 | 1/3/2020 |     10 |
+----+----------+--------+
```

the first date listed for ID 1 would be their first order process date. The second date would be their second. There can be several process dates for each ID. The process date for ID 2 is their first process date. There can be dates where no processing occurs per ID, with the next date several days from the previous max date (eg 1/2/2020 -> 2/15/2020).

I need an output where ID 1 would have columns that show amount processed by day as defined by day from start. ID 1's min date would have amount 40, min date +1 50, mind date + 2 0 for example. ID 2 would have min date 10, min date +1 0, min date + 2 0, etc.

Output would look like this

```
+----+---------+--------+
| ID |   Day   | Amount |
+----+---------+--------+
|  1 | 1       |     40 |
|  1 | 2       |     50 |
|  2 | 1       |     10 |
+----+---------+--------+
```

How to go about this?

Comment: Please show us the result that you expect, as tabular text. It might also be useful to add a few more rows of data.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking to rank records having the same `id` by increasing `day`.

If you are running MySQL, that's exactly what `row_number()` does:

```
select t.*, row_number() over(partition by id order by day) new_id
from mytable t
```

You might also want to have a look at `rank()` and `dense_rank()`, depending on how you want to manage potential ties (ie records having the same `id` and `day`).